# Why is CONVERT(TIME(7), expression) not deterministic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns

I have an existing table I would like to add a computed column

```
[dbo].[Route]
   ...
   [EstimatedArrival] TIME (7) NOT NULL,
   [DriveSeconds]     INT      NOT NULL,
   [WaitSeconds]      INT      NOT NULL,
   ...
```

But when I tried to add computed column of `TIME` below

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Route]
  ADD [EstimatedDeparture] AS 
  CONVERT (TIME (7), DATEADD(SECOND, 
    (((DATEPART(HOUR, [EstimatedArrival]) * 3600) 
     + (DATEPART(MINUTE, [EstimatedArrival]) * 60)  
     + DATEPART(SECOND, [EstimatedArrival])) 
     - [DriveSeconds] - [WaitSeconds]), ''), 114) 
  PERSISTED;
```

it throws

> Computed column 'EstimatedDeparture' in table 'Route' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

Why? I thought `CONVERT(TIME (7) ...)` should guarantee the column type as `TIME`

Note that if I use this Convert expression in query, it works fine.
How do I fix this problem?

Comment: @HABO as it turns out, there *is* a string format in there (note the `''`), and the 114 doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is this empty string supposed to represent?

```
- [DriveSeconds] - [WaitSeconds]), ''), 114) 
-----------------------------------^^
```

This likely tells SQL Server you're going to be interpreting part of this as a string. While I agree with HABO that you don't need the 114 style either, I was able to make this work using the following, which still uses the unnecessary style number:

```
- [DriveSeconds] - [WaitSeconds]), 0), 114)
```

Whether that still retains the proper calculation, I'm not sure, since I don't know what the intent is, but avoiding implicit conversions to strings here should avoid the problem.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx), this is the `date` argument of `DATEADD`. Setting it to 0 fixes the problem. Brilliant!

Comment: Also I agree 114 is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can correct and simplify it this way:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Route]
ADD [EstimatedDeparture] AS 
CONVERT (TIME (7), DATEADD(SECOND, - [DriveSeconds] - [WaitSeconds], [EstimatedArrival]))
PERSISTED;
```